# SharePoint 2010 Search Query String issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, search-scope, enterprise-search

Hi We are using default out of the box sharepoint 2010 search. the search seems to be working fine in the dev setup. while moving to our QA environmnet, the search doesnt seems to work and I narrowed down the issue to the Query String Parameter 'U' refering Contextual Scope URL.

URL -

```
https://QA.mysite.com/sites/library/_layouts/searchpage.aspx?k=employee&cs=This%20Site&u=https%3A%2F%2FQA.mysite.com%2Fsites%2Flibrary
```

Now when i remove **&u=https%3A%2F%2FQA.mysite.com%2Fsites%2Flibrary** from the URL the search seems to displaying the results.

Can anyone please advise me on what is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

The u parameter is a context scope parameter and limits the results to the site encoded in the parameter. In your case thats: https://QA.mysite.com/sites/library
If your dev and QA env have different urls that would explain why you wont get results in one of them.